# How to transform a table of dataset to a matrix in R

Tags: r, datatable, transform

I have a dataset like this

```
df <- data.frame("col1" = c("a", "b", "a", "c", "d", "e", "f", "c"), "col2" = c("v2", "v2", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v1", "v2", "v4"), "index" = c(3,1,3,0,1,2,3,0))
```

And I hope to get a matrix like this:

```
  v1 v2 v2 v3 v4
a 0  3  3  0  0
b 0  1  0  0  0
c 0  0  0  0  0
d 0  0  0  0  1
e 2  0  0  0  0
f 0  3  0  0  0
```

Thank you very much for your answer!!

Comment: try `tidyr::spread`

Comment: You can try: `table(df)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have unique identifier in your groups and have values (`V2`) repeated. We can `complete` `col1` and `col2` values and `fill` `index` with 0. Create a unique identifier for each group (`col1`) and then `spread` the values.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  complete(col1, col2, fill = list(index = 0)) %>% 
  group_by(col1) %>%
  mutate(col2 = paste0("V", row_number())) %>%
  spread(col2, index, fill = 0)

#  col1     V1    V2    V3    V4    V5
#  <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 a         0     3     3     0     0
#2 b         0     1     0     0     0
#3 c         0     0     0     0     0
#4 d         0     0     0     1     0
#5 e         2     0     0     0     0
#6 f         0     3     0     0     0
```

Comment: What if I want to keep the duplicated v2 ?

Comment: @JimmyLee the duplicated `V2` is still there it is just renamed as `V3`. If you want to rename it keep it as `V2` you can add `%>% 
  rename_at(4,~"V2")` at the end in the chain.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this easily in `base R`

```
xtabs(index ~ col1 + col2, unique(df))
#  col2
#col1 v1 v2 v3 v4
#   a  0  3  0  0
#   b  0  1  0  0
#   c  0  0  0  0
#   d  0  0  0  1
#   e  2  0  0  0
#   f  0  3  0  0
```

NOTE: No packages loaded